# Unclickable blogger themes after adding auto adsense ads

Tags: blogger, adsense

Links in contempo, soho, emporio and notable Blogger themes become unclickable after adding auto adsense ads, this only happens on mobile devices. 
Any feedback will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this happened with me too, but only on mobile devices. The links works just fine on PC, with auto ads on the page. Though it doesn't happen anymore.
The only thing I can think I modified is I removed the already existing Adsense code from Emporio Template.
If you want to try that, follow these steps:

1. Go to Themes in Blogger dashboard.
2. Make a backup of your existing theme.
3. Edit html
4. Search for Adsense1 and Adsense2 (they are stacked on top of one another)
5. remove them (if you don't know how to remove them whole, google it, there are plenty of guides).
6. Save the theme.

Now try the auto ads.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, it is working now after I removed the Adsense1 and Adsense2 ads from the theme.